# Update files to the filter that move first row in the index bar

Tags: excel, excel-2019

I have recently moved from Excel 2013 to Excel 2019.

I have noticed that, with Excel 2019, when I now use Filter on the first row, it will then automatically move the first row filters and names in the index bar when scrolling. Like this:

[image]

I have also noticed that if the document was made with a Filter from a previous Excel version, the filter still exist, however it does not move the first row into the index bar.

To update the Filter to the newest version, I have found only one solution: remove the older version and place again the newest, but in the process I also lose the currently set filters.

I find this feature really great, and I would like to update a large set of documents. However it is important that I conserve the current filters as they are currently set

Would you have a solution to update all the files in a simpler way?
Very helpful would be a solutions to update filters without changing current filters, even more helpful would be to be able to update all files together.